# OOP Python - define purchase method, looking for target code in a list of items that have code no, description, price and qty

Tags: python

The `ShoppingItem` class has been defined.

```
class ShoppingItem:
    def __init__(self, code, description, price=1.0, quantity=1):
        self.code = int(code)
        self.description = str(description)
        self.price = float(price)
        self.quantity = int(quantity)
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.quantity == 0:
            return ("Code = {}, {} - Out of Stock".format(self.code, self.description))
        else:
            return ("Code = {}, {}, ${:.2f}, quantity = {}".format(self.code, self.description, self.price, self.quantity))
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return ("ShoppingItem({}, '{}', {}, {})".format(self.code,self.description, self.price, self.quantity ))
        
    def set_price(self, new_price):
        if new_price > 0:
            self.price = new_price
```

I have also defined another class - `Shopping`

```
class Shopping:
    def __init__(self, filename = 'stocks.txt'):
        self.filename = filename
        Shopping.items_list = []
            
    def search(self, target_code): #issue is here
        self.target_code = target_code
        for index in range(len(Shopping.items_list)):
            if Shopping.items_list[index].code == self.target_code:
                return (Shopping.items_list[index])
                
    def purchase(self, target_code):
        self.target_code = target_code
        for index in range(len(Shopping.items_list)):
            if Shopping.items_list[index].code == self.target_code:
                if Shopping.items_list[index].quantity != 0:
                    print ("{} ${:.2f}".format(Shopping.items_list[index].description,Shopping.items_list[index].price))
                    Shopping.items_list[index].quantity -= 1
                else:
                    print ("{} Out of Stock!".format(Shopping.items_list[index].code))
            else:
                print ("{} Not Found!".format(self.target_code))
```

I am facing problem in the `purchase(self, target_code)` method. My output is totally different from what is expected.

Comment: Your `print("...Not Found")` cannot be inside the loop.  You can't say it wasn't found until you have looked at EVERY item, after the loop has ended.  You'll need to use a "found" flag (or use the `for`/`else` trick that Python has).  Alternatively, and more sensibly, you could store your shopping list in a dictionary with the item number as the key.  Then, Python will do the lookup for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `purchase` method is not returning anything, which is the cause of the exception (the `cost` variable is of `NoneType`). You should return the cost of shopping item to be purchased (through `return Shopping.items_list[index].price` if the item is found, or `return 0` if the item is not found in `items_list`).

Also, like what Tim has mentioned, the `print("...Not Found")` statement is being called once per loop. To fix that, you would have to print that ONLY if the code does not exist in the `items_list`. You can consider changing `items_list` to a Python dict (since the ordering of your items are not important), or using Python's `for/else`, which you can find more information a bout [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html).